# Code attached to watch: {} never executes although the watched variable does indeed change

Tags: vue.js, watch

I can't seem to be able to watch my variable `form.ac_all`, which I know for sure does change over time:

```
data () {
    return {
        form: {
            ac_all: false
        }
    } 
},
watch: {
    form: {
        ac_all () {
        console.log(form.ac_all)
        }
    }
}
```

As the variable is nested I tried with `deep` option just in case, to no avail:

```
data () {
    return {
        form: {
            ac_all: false
        }
    } 
},
watch: {
    form: {
        ac_all: {
            handler () {
                console.log(form.ac_all)
            },
            deep: true
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: To `watch` nested properties you need to write `'form.ac_all'` as the property name. Just nesting objects within the `watch` won't work. So `watch: { 'form.ac_all': function () { ... } }`. See the `e.f` example in the official documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
        form: {
            ac_all: false
        }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    'form.ac_all'() {
        console.log('form.ac_all value is ' + this.form.ac_all)
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="form.ac_all = !form.ac_all">Toggle</button>
</div>
```